# Is there a purpose to the war missions in X3:Albion Prelude?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I have stumbled across a couple of war missions in X3:Albion Prelude and have been sadly unimpressed: "deliver this radioactive waste, it's critical to the war effort!"  I see that war missions only appear in the red "war" sectors but I can't seem to find a theme or story behind the war other than the Albion missions.

Am I missing something?  Is there a real war story here in Omicron Lyrae or should I head back to Albion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You may get a mission to fight the enemy in a contested sector, and some sectors may occasionally change hands, but there is no real story to be experienced or goal to be reached.

Comment: when you say sectors change hands, does the sector government officially change from Argon to Terran and vice versa as seen on the universe map?

Comment: @yx. yes, though it happens way too infrequently.

Comment: that's a shame, the conflicts mod for x3tc was one of my favorite mods, I was hoping they'd integrate some of that into x3ap

Answer (score 2):

The "war missions" are pre-reqs for plot progression; you need to do 3 I think before you get the first part of the Albion plot, then a few more for the 2nd part. You'll see how many you've done in the pilot profile.

When you have "Trial by fire" - "Aid: The war effort" in your mission dialog this is what it wants you to do. The voice overheads are nonsense that appear to bear little or no relation to the war missions.

It also seems like any mission accepted in a war sector is a war mission. which is lucky, because the damn things spawn incredibly rarely.

Answer (score 0):

I know that if you start a vanilla game as the top pick selectable character (the argon peacekeeper I think) you actually get a set of missions that tell a story or a "plot". Some of the mods have the Albion plot turned off though so check on that if you cant find the plot missions. I believe the "war missions" in the front line sectors are just a way to make money between the plot missions.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant when I referred to heading back to Albion.  There's a cheevo for completing that storyline on Steam.

Comment: You an also get it from other starts once you build appropriate rep with the Argon. I did as Argon Patriot, it just took a while before the mission became available.